# Automation server can't create object, ie7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, activex

```
var fSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fh = fSO.CreateTextFile(path + fileName + ".xml", true, true);
```

I get the following javascript error: `Automation server can't create object`, even though all my ActiveX settings are enabled in IE that i can think of (ActiveX and plug-ins section). The browser that i'm using for this is IE7.

What could possibly cause this errormessage?

Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Internet options > Security > Custom Level
Under the ActiveX controls and plug-ins, select Enable for Initializing and Script ActiveX controls not marked as safe